# Amazon EBS Multi-Attach on Provisioned IOPS io1 volumes not replication data across instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume

We are trying to use single Multi-Attach EBS Provisioned IOPS io1 volume as log storage for spot instances. If we place some data on the volume it's not replicating data on other instances (Attached same volume). I have used xfs file system.

Anyone knows how to fix. or alternate way to replicate the data

Comment: There is also EFS for sharing file system across instance. But why would Multi-Attach not work? Any errors somewhere?

Comment: EFS is a too much costly compare to EBS io1 volume single AZ as per our use case. not error multi attach work fine but data replication is not working as standard behavior. like -  the same volume attached with 2 system if i place some data in first instance its not showing on second one

Comment: Amazon EBS does not replicate data across volumes. If you have installed some software to do this (xfs?), then the problem probably lies with that software, not Amazon EBS.

Comment: I mean to say - I used a single EBS volume attached on 2 machines and the volume formatted with XFS file system. if I place any data on that volume it should be available on both machines.

Comment: any solution for the above?